# Question about placing of indices in tetrads/vierbein

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, conventions, covariance

I'm going to use boldface to denote the metric tensor as a geometric rank 2 tensor and I'll expand it in different basis. First, let's define the coordinate vector and 1-form basis

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{e}^\mu&=dx^\mu \\
\vec{e}_\mu&=\partial_\mu
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

In coordinate basis, the metric is

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{g} =g_{\mu \nu } \tilde{e}^\mu \tilde{e}^\nu
\end{equation}

I'll use latin indices for orthonormal basis $\vec{e}_a$ and $\tilde{e}^a$ satisfying

\begin{equation}
\vec{e}_a \cdot \vec{e}_b =g_{\mu\nu} e_a^{\ \  \mu }e_b^{\ \  \nu}=\eta_{ab}
\end{equation}

where $\eta_{ab}$ is the Minkowski metric. The metric tensor in this basis is

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{g} =\eta_{ab} \tilde{e}^a \tilde{e}^b
\end{equation}

I can also rewrite the metric from one basis to another one

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{g}& =g_{\mu \nu } \tilde{e}^\mu \tilde{e}^\nu \\
&= g_{\mu \nu }e^\mu_{\ \ a} e^\nu_{\ \ b}\tilde{e}^a \tilde{e}^b
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now, by comparing this equation to the metric in orthonormal basis, we get

\begin{equation}
\eta_{ab}=g_{\mu \nu }e^\mu_{\ \ a} e^\nu_{\ \ b}
\end{equation}

But from the orthonormality condition we had

\begin{equation}
\eta_{ab}=g_{\mu \nu }e_a^{\ \ \mu} e_b^{\ \ \nu}
\end{equation}

I am almost certain that $e_a^{\ \ \mu}\neq e^\mu_{\ \ a}$ so where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Have you made a check for a curved spacetime of Kerr metric or a Schwarzschild?

Comment: It is true that $e_a^{\ \ \mu}=e_{\ \ a}^\mu$ on Schwarzschild but I wasn't sure if it was a consecuence of the metric being diagonal! I tried doing the calculations on Kerr but they are a bit too long so I'm still working on that.

Comment: "I am almost certain that ${e_a}^{\mu}\neq {e^{\mu}}_a$ ... " Why so? Is there a reason for introducing two different notations ${e^{\mu}}_a$ and ${e_a}^{\mu}$ as in orthonormal condition?